publish secure data to thingspeak (micropython) TLS
I recently startd a project on IOT.  I use micropython, MQTT, ESP32, DHT11.
At first step I published my DHT11 sensor data on thingspeak and visualized (port 1883). Now I want to publish secure data on port 8883 and use thingspeak certificate , ..
I downloaded thingspeak.crt and put it in /etc/ssl/certs/  and wrote these codes but it doesn't connect to server. Could anyone tell me what should I do more? I really appreciate your help.
 
import network
from umqtt.robust import MQTTClient
import time
import dht
from machine import Pin
import sys
#=======================================================
# Configuration parameters

wifi_ssid = ''
wifi_password = ''
thingspeak_address = 'ssl://mqtt3.thingspeak.com'
thingspeak_mqtt_client_id = ' '
thingspeak_mqtt_username = ''
thingspeak_mqtt_password = ''
thingspeak_channel_id = ''
publish_period_in_sec = 20
mqtt_port =8883
thingspeak_crt_path = '/etc/ssl/certs/thingspeak-com.crt'
#=======================================================
# connect the device to the WiFi network

wifi = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wifi.active(True)
wifi.connect(wifi_ssid, wifi_password)

# wait until the device is connected to the WiFi network
if not wifi.isconnected():
    print('connecting to wifi ...')
    while not wifi.isconnected():
        pass
else:
    print('wifi connected! Network config:', wifi.ifconfig())
    
#=======================================================
# connect to Thingspeak MQTT broker - unsecure TCP (port 1883)

client = MQTTClient(server = thingspeak_address,
                    client_id = thingspeak_mqtt_client_id, 
                    user = thingspeak_mqtt_username, 
                    password = thingspeak_mqtt_password, 
                    ssl=True,
                    port = mqtt_port,
                    ssl_params={"ca_certs": thingspeak_crt_path})
                    
try:            
    client.connect()
    print('Connect to MQTT server!')
except Exception as e:
    print('could not connect to MQTT server {}{}'.format(type(e).__name__, e))
    sys.exit();

#=======================================================


What error messages do you get?

when it tries to connect to the server, I get "OSERROR -202" on the command "client.connect()"

And you've searched to see what that error code means?

I searched but haven't found anything.

Searching implies that the -202 error means that the device is not actually connected to the wifi

it is already connected to wifi.
it cannot connect to ThingSpeak. I have problem with this part of code >>
client = MQTTClient(server = thingspeak_address,
client_id = thingspeak_mqtt_client_id,
user = thingspeak_mqtt_username,
password = thingspeak_mqtt_password,
ssl=True,
port = mqtt_port,
ssl_params={"ca_certs": thingspeak_crt_path})

have you done anything similar?
